# Robust least squares in Octave

Tags: signal-processing, octave, mathematical-optimization, least-squares

I am programming the [classical Prony's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prony%27s_method) (or sometimes Prony's analysis) using Octave. The script works pretty fine on a test signal such as:

```
t = 1:600;
sig = exp(-0.01*t).*cos(0.1*t);
```

but totally collapses when even a small amount of noise is added:

```
sig = sig + 0.001*rand(size(sig));
```

The issue is computing the overdetermined set of equations using `pinv` when the linear prediction is bulit (see the link above). I need something more robust and less sensitive to outliers. Sadly, no function in the Octave core helped me so far. I have tried `ols` and `lscov` but they don't do the trick.

Any hints, please?

**Note:** I am aware that the classic Prony is very problematic just because of this issues and there are modified algorithms (such as [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313858955_A_Robust_Prony_Method_for_Power_System_Electromechanical_Modes_Identification)). I just feel that I haven't done the maximum for the classic method to work. Using a better solver it should persist this kind of noise.

Comment: This question would be greatly improved by including your implementation of Prony's method (or some concise version thereof)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the difference in timescale between the noise and the underlying damped-sinusoid. The lowest order of difference equation that could  match your damped-sinusoid is second-order, so span only three adjacent timesteps. But such a model would be very likely to overfit the noise signal simply because the sinusoid has a period of dozens of samples. If the noise is weak enough, you may be able to use Prony's method by regularizing the pseudo-inverse by diagonal loading and/or increasing the order of the model so that the prediction filter spans a wider time extent.